# Animation transferred to character by rokoko addon. Animation runs but is offset

Tags: rigging

I am currently trying to solve a big problem for myself. This is the first time I want to participate in a 3D challenge. So far everything has gone quite well and I have been on schedule.

In the given scene, a character runs up a flight of stairs. I have modelled my character for this and now want to transfer it to this animation. There was also a tutorial from the organiser.
I uploaded my model to Mixamo and then downloaded it again as a T-Pose. I integrated it into my scene and then used the Rokoko addon to create a rig transfer / animation transfer. The animation runs. Unfortunately, it's slightly offset (see screenshot). I don't know how to fix this. My character has to walk in exactly the same position as the animation.

[image]
[image]

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this. I have already asked in a few other communities and have not found an answer.

I would also like to know if it is possible for some of the objects in my character to move with the animation but not deform, as they are actually made of metal. However, my first question is more important.

Regards
Sascha